# Gatling running multiple simulations with Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gatling

The Gradle plugin (https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gatling-gradle-plugin, v2.1) claims `The ability to configure multiple simulations per gradle project`

Given the following gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

group '****'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.commercehub:gatling-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    }

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

ext {
    SCALA_VERSION = "2.11.7"
    GATLING_VERSION = "2.2.3"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${SCALA_VERSION}"

    testCompile 'com.typesafe:config:1.3.1'
    testCompile "io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:${GATLING_VERSION}"
    testCompile "io.gatling:gatling-test-framework:${GATLING_VERSION}"
}


apply plugin: 'gatling'

import com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.GatlingTask
task loadTest(type: GatlingTask, dependsOn: ['testClasses']) {
    gatlingSimulation = 'HealthSimulation,PlaceAttributesSimulation'
    jvmOptions {
        jvmArgs = [
            "-Dlogback.configurationFile=${logbackGatlingConfig()}",
            "-Denv=${System.getProperty('env', 'stg')}",
        ]
        minHeapSize = "1024m"
        maxHeapSize = "1024m"
    }
}

def logbackGatlingConfig() {
    return sourceSets.test.resources.find { it.name == 'logback-gatling.xml' }
}
```

in particular the line `gatlingSimulation = 'HealthSimulation,PlaceAttributesSimulation'`, I would expect both simulation to be run. Why? Because looking at the Gradle plugin, `gatlingSimulation` is then passed to Gatling `-s` flag.

Long story short, Gatling `-s` does not support multiple simulations anymore (see https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/363 for details), so I think I am missing a bit in the gradle plugin I am using to enable multiple simulations.

Both simulations run fine when run individually, but if I try to run them together, Gatling stucks asking which one to execute. Any suggestion how to achieve running multiple simulations (sequentially) in the same gradle project?

**EDIT**: my currently ugly workaround (suggestions welcome to make it less ugly, but still workaround imo) is to modify the Gradle build file with:

```
task loadTests;
fileTree(dir: 'src/test').include("**/*Simulation.scala").each {target ->

    ext {
        filename = target.toString()
        filename = filename.substring(filename.indexOf("scala") + "scala".length() + 1)
        filename = filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf(".")).replaceAll("/", ".")
    }

    task("loadTest${filename}", type: GatlingTask, dependsOn: 'testClasses', description : "Load test ${filename}s") {
        gatlingSimulation = filename
        jvmOptions {
            jvmArgs = [
                "-Dlogback.configurationFile=${logbackGatlingConfig()}",
                "-Denv=${System.getProperty('env', 'stg')}",
            ]
            minHeapSize = "1024m"
            maxHeapSize = "1024m"
        }
    }
    loadTests.dependsOn("loadTest${filename}")
}

def logbackGatlingConfig() {
    return sourceSets.test.resources.find { it.name == 'logback-gatling.xml' }
}
```

Basically, I create a `GatlingTask` for each `*Simulation.scala` file (naming convention) and then create a bulk `loadTests` task that depends on all.

Comment: is this a resolved issue or still unresolved?

Comment: I'd say unresolved. I did not write any more performance tests in the past 2 years and what I described is the solution I ended up with in this forgotten prototype

Comment: using the gradle plugin as explained here can be a work around it can run multiple simulations   https://james-willett.com/2017/04/running-gatling-through-gradle/